# Can't update row in database

Tags: php, mysql, sql, drupal-7

I try to update a row in a database, but I can't do that. Here is my sql:

```
$sql = "UPDATE `voting_nomination_counter` 
 SET  `quantity`=quantity+1 
 WHERE `nid` = '$nid'  
 AND nominee = '$nominee'";
```

I suspect the problem is here - `AND nominee = '$nominee'";`  because when I remove this from the query all works and updates fine. Help, please.

Comment: If you aren't getting a sql error (assuming you have shown errors) output the sql query string and see if the variables are what you expect.

Comment: Check whether you have any value there in $nominee

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve this problem, if I want to update `WHERE string = string` I just need to use this statement `UPDATE table SET field = REPLACE(field, 'string', 'anothervalue') WHERE field LIKE '%string%';`, thanks guys!)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$sql = "UPDATE voting_nomination_counter SET quantity=quantity+1 WHERE nid = '$nid' AND nominee = '$nominee'";
```

Comment: Is there any difference here except you removed the backticks in the original SQL which are perfectly okay to use?

Answer (score 0):

@excluded_once Looks like you were able to solve your issue. So in future do not ever use variable names directly into SQL string. Always use db_query or db_select and then always bind the variables into SQL, it will help you prevent from SQL injections and other attacks.